# Using google feed api with php

Tags: php, google-feed-api

`<?php
    extract($_GET);
    $data = file_get_contents("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find?v=1.0&q=" . $category );
    echo json_decode($data);
?>`

This is giving me an error : Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: the json decoded data is now an object, treat it as such

Comment: `extract($_GET)` is very evil then you can use register globals its much easier :D and very deprecated :D

Comment: `$data` is an object, so you can't `echo` it. You can `print_r` it to get an idea of its structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/find?v=1.0&q=".$_GET["query"]);
$object = json_decode($data);

if(count($object->responseData->entries)>0){
    foreach($object->responseData->entries as $entry){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($entry);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}else{
    echo 'no data';
}
?>
```

you have to call it by http://example.com/thisfile.php?query=my_text